# Analyzing an algorithm with recurrence T(n) = T(n - 1) + T(n - 2) + T(n -3)?

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory, big-o

So, someone posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239861/how-would-i-get-the-order-of-algorithm-tn-tn-1tn-2-tn-3#comment24985291_17239861) earlier, but essentially no effort was put into it, it was poorly tagged and then closed.  Nonetheless, I think it could have been a good question.  I'm posting because according to the OP, my answer (posted in a comment) did not agree with the solution. So, I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing incorrectly (assuming that the answer that he has in indeed correct):

We have:

```
T(N) = T(N-1) + T(N-2) + T(N-3)
```

where N > 3.  He didn't have a base case listed, but since N > 3, I assumed that there are probably 3 base cases for `T(3)`, `T(2)` and `T(1)` .  To calculate `T(K)`, we do the following:

```
T(K) = T(K-1) + T(K-2) + T(K-3)
```

Then we must calculate:

```
T(K-1) = T((K-1)-1) + T((K-1)-2) + T((K-1)-3)
T(K-2) = T((K-2)-1) + T((K-2)-2) + T((K-2)-3)
T(K-3) = T((K-3)-1) + T((K-3)-2) + T((K-3)-3)
```

and so on...
Here's a tree-representation:

```
L0                                                  T(K)
                      /                              |                              \
L1               T(K-1)                            T(K-2)                           T(K-3)
          /         |     \                 /        |          \                 /   |     \
L2   T((K-1)-1) T((K-1)-2) T((K-1)-3)  T((K-2)-1) T((K-2)-2) T((K-2)-3) T((K-3)-1) T((K-3)-2) T((K-3)-3)    
                 ...                                ...                                ...
```

So we have 3 children, then 9 children, then 27 children,..., until we hit our base cases.  Hence, the algorithm is `O(3^(N-3))`, the `N-3` is there to account for the three base cases, ie after T(4), we can only have bases cases, no more branching.

The actual solution was never provided, but like I said, I'm told that this is incorrect.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this even make sense in the context of an algorithm?  When subtraction of the time for a sub-problem ever occur?

Comment: I'm not sure where the initial question came from.  Nonetheless, one can still derive an answer, no?  If I'm doing something incorrectly, please tell me.

Comment: cool, thanks for posting the question! the answer and comments are pretty amazing!

Comment: your title has subtraction, the body of the question has only sum, probably something should be corrected...

Comment: @maxim1000, I edited it.  There was an issue when templatetypedef edited it, but since it didn't detract from my original question, I didn't care.  There's also the possibility that the OP actually submitted the question incorrectly.  Nonetheless, the answer/comments provided are good, so I just made the necessary changes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The recurrence you have set up is the following:

> T(n) = T(n - 1) + T(n - 2) + T(n - 3)

I assume the base cases are probably

> T(0) = T(1) = T(2) = 1

If you start to expand out the terms of this recurrence, you get

- T(0) = 1
- T(1) = 1
- T(2) = 1
- T(3) = 3
- T(4) = 5
- T(5) = 9
- T(6) = 17
- T(7) = 31
- ...

There doesn't seem to be an obvious pattern here.  Fortunately, we can go to the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences and punch in the terms 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17 and you'll find that this is the [Tribonacci sequence](http://oeis.org/search?q=1,%201,%201,%203,%205,%209,%2017&sort=&language=english&go=Search) whose first three terms are 1.

If you look at the information about the Tribonacci numbers, you'll see the following:

> a(n)/a(n-1) tends to the tribonacci constant, 1.839286755...

(here, a(n) is the notation the site uses for my T(n)).  Since the ratio of consecutive terms of the Tribonacci sequence tends to approximately 1.839286755, we know that the Tribonacci sequence must be exponentially growing, and it grows exponentially at a rate that is approximately Θ(1.839286755<sup>n</sup>).  (Compare this to the Fibonacci sequence, which is known to grow at Θ(φ<sup>n</sup>), where φ is the golden ratio).  Doing some further reading on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Tribonacci_numbers) gives this formula for the Tribonacci constant:

[image]

and confirms the exponential growth rate.

Consequently, we can conclude that the runtime is Θ(1.839286755<sup>n</sup>).

So... how would you compute this on your own?  The easiest way to do this (and I think the way that these values are known) is to use [generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function).  You can try to derive a generating function for the recurrence you have written out here, then try to rewrite the generating function in a closed-form to get the exact value.  This is one way to get the closed-form for Fibonacci numbers, and it should generalize here (though it might be a lot of slogging through unpleasant math.)  Alternatively, as @tmyklebu points out, you could write out this matrix:

```
     | 0 1 0 |
 M = | 0 0 1 |
     | 1 1 1 |
```

and compute its eigenvalues, the largest of which will come out to the Tribonacci constant.  (Note that this matrix has the property that

```
 | 0 1 0 |   |a|   |    b    |
 | 0 0 1 | x |b| = |    c    |
 | 1 1 1 |   |c|   |a + b + c|
```

Consequently, if you put three consecutive values from the recurrence into a column vector v and compute Mv, you get back a new column vector holding the latter two values from the recurrence, plus the next value in the recurrence.  In this way, you can compute the kth value of the recurrence by computing M<sup>k</sup>v and looking at the first component of the vector.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: The easiest way to derive it on your own is probably to write down a matrix that takes [T(n-3), T(n-2), T(n-1)] to [T(n-2), T(n-1), T(n)].  If the largest eigenvalue of this matrix is lambda, then the recurrence's solutions are Theta(P(n) lambda^n) where P is a polynomial whose degree is the multiplicity of the eigenvalue lambda.

Comment: That's a good point, though IIRC proving that that approach will work is not trivial.

Comment: It's not too bad.  Pretty easy in the case where the matrix is diagonalisable.  You diagonalise the matrix---you write M = A^(-1) D A.  Then M^n = A^(-1) D^n A.  It's straightforward to work out what the nth power of a diagonal matrix is.  In the nondiagonalisable case, you take D to be M's Jordan form.  Then you screw around a little bit working out bounds on the entries of the nth power of a Jordan block.

Comment: Interesting, but with respect to the number of function calls, if you only use the given equation, is it O(3^(N-3))?

Comment: @tmyklebu, could you please elaborate on your first comment?  I'm not sure that I understand the motivation.  Perhaps you could give it in an answer, so that it's easier to look at?

Comment: @tmyklebu amazing comment about how to generally compute it!

Comment: @SteveP. just take the jordan form and screw around a little bit! haha.. just pulling your leg. basically it builds upon a whole bunch of matrix math which would probably be difficult to teach. see the matrix in the answer `M`, repeated multiplications amount to recursing the recurrence. then read up the notion of eigenvalues and diagonalization. i would say that'd be a short math course all together so just understanding it as Tribonacci should be good enough. it is exponential though.

Comment: @SteveP.- It is technically correct to say that the runtime is O(3^{n-3}).  Note that this is identical to saying the runtime is O(3^n), since 3^{n-3} = 3^n / 27 = O(3^n).  However, this is a weak upper bound and can be tightened significantly.

Comment: @randomstring, I'm actually quite familiar with linear algebra; I know all about eigenvalues and diagonalization, I'm just not sure how that matrix was constructed.  I don't understand: "[T(n-3), T(n-2), T(n-1)] to [T(n-2), T(n-1), T(n)]." and how that translates to the 3x3 given matrix.  I tend to need things very explicitly written.

Comment: @templatetypedef, yeah I understand that, I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing anything.  Thanks!

Comment: @SteveP.- I just updated the answer to show you where the matrix came from.  I hope this helps!

Comment: @SteveP.- Oh wow, I totally missed that!  This invalidates this answer entirely.  Are you **sure** that's the recurrence for the algorithm runtime?  It's very rare to see a minus term thrown in there.

Comment: @templatetypedef, sorry I accidentally deleted my comment...That's what was in the original post.  It's quite possible that it was a typi. :)  Nonetheless, it was a good answer, so let it be, I guess.

Comment: SteveP. sorry i am usually blind to details unless the problem is really important to me. the recurrence in the answer is different from the one in the question - i didn't see it before. i thought your concern was not the recurrence but the matrix eigenvalue method. anyways, i think that @tmyklebu comment is the only hope for an answer.

Answer (score 12):

This is a cool method that I learned, so I thought I'll share it with you.It's really simple to estimate the time complexity.
Looking at the recurrence we guess that the time complexity is exponential.

**Lets say:**

```
T(N)=x^n
```

**The given recurrence is**

```
T(N) = T(N-1) + T(N-2) + T(N-3)
```

**Substituting**

```
 x^n = x^n-1  + x^n-2  + x^n-3
Dividing throughout by x^n-3
 x^3 = x^2    + x^1    + 1
Rearranging
 x^3 - x^2 - x - 1=0
```

You can find out it's cubic roots [here](http://www.1728.org/cubic.htm).

This cubic equation has one real root(  1.8392867552141612) and two complex roots(of magnitude 0.7373527).

Thus asymptotically our algorithm's running time is bounded by **T(N)=1.839^n**.

Comment: With this methodology, is there a safeguard in case our assumption is incorrect?  For this example, obviously the runtime is exponential, but let's just pretend that we didn't know for sure, but just assumed exponential (but that's not actually the case).  "At the end", how would we know if our assumption was incorrect?

Comment: That's a great question!It's applicable for linear recurrences where you can expect exponential running time.For example in the given case you expect something like 3^n.I think if the assumption is invalid,you would get invalid roots(negative roots).

Comment: @SteveP.: The family of solutions to this recurrence can be seen to be a vector space of dimension 3. If we have three linearly independent solutions `f`, `g` and `h`, any solutions thus reads `af + bg + ch`. Now `n^\alpha`, where `\alpha` is one of the three roots of the polynomial `x^3 - x^2 - x - 1` form three independent solutions.

Comment: @Aravind  thanks for answering! i hope your answer applies. there is an error in the example you have used. in the original question the last term is subtracted rather than added. would your method still generate the correct answer?

Comment: Nope, as you can see, I have taken it straight from the question.Apparently the heading was different from the question.Now the heading is fixed!As someone else has pointed, in algorithms you don't usually get negative terms in the recurrence.

Answer (score 0):

As a few people have noticed, this recurrence is different than the original recurrence `T(N) = T(N-1) + T(N-2) - T(N-3)`.  I prefer the approach of assuming `T(N)=x^N` given by @Aravind.  With this recurrence, you get the characteristic equation `x^3-x^2-x+1=(x-1)^2(x+1)`.  (This will be the characteristic equation for the matrix approach of @templatetypedef, and the denominator of the generating function if you took that approach.)

The repeated root causes all sorts of difficulties.  The matrix isn't diagonalizable.  The generating function has a repeated denominator when you factor it.  When you assume `T(N)=x^N`, you only get two linearly independent solutions, and need a third.

In general, when you assume `T(N)=x^N` and get a double root `r`, that means the linearly independent solutions are `r^N` and `N*r^N` (a triple root would introduce `N^2*r^N`).  So in our case, the three linearly independent solutions to the recurrence are `(-1)^N`, `1^N=1`, and `N*1^N=N`.  This means that a general solution is `T(N)=A(-1)^N+B+C*N`, and you  use the initial conditions to determine `A`, `B`, and `C`.  If `C!=0`, then `T(N)=Θ(N)`, otherwise `T(N)=Θ(1)`.  Which is probably not that realistic for an algorithm.