# Complexity of the recursion: T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + C

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity, recurrence, asymptotic-complexity

I want to understand how to arrive at the complexity of the below recurrence relation.

`T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + C`
Given `T(1) = C` and `T(2) = 2C;`

Generally for equations like `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + C` (Given T(1) = C), I use the following method.

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + C
=> T(n) = 4T(n/4) + 3C
=> T(n) = 8T(n/8) + 7C
=> ...
=> T(n) = 2^k T (n/2^k) + (2^k - 1) c
```

Now when `n/2^k = 1 => K = log (n)` (to the base 2)

```
T(n) = n T(1) + (n-1)C
     = (2n -1) C
     = O(n)
```

But, I'm not able to come up with similar approach for the problem I have in question. Please correct me if my approach is incorrect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The complexity is related to input-size, where each call produce a binary-tree of calls

Where `T(n)` make `2`<sup>`n`</sup> calls in total ..

`T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + C`

`T(n) = O(2`<sup>`n-1`</sup>`) + O(2`<sup>`n-2`</sup>`) + O(1)`

`O(2`<sup>`n`</sup>`)`

In the same fashion, you can generalize your recursive function, as a Fibonacci number

`T(n) = F(n) + ( C * 2`<sup>`n`</sup>`)`

Next you can use a direct formula instead of recursive way

Using a complex method known as [Binet's Formula](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html)

Answer (score 5):

If you were also interested in finding an explicit formula for `T(n)` this may help.

We know that `T(1) = c` and `T(2) = 2c` and `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + c`.

So just write `T(n)` and start expanding.

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + c
T(n) = 2*T(n-2) + T(n-3) + 2c
T(n) = 3*T(n-3) + 2*T(n-4) + 4c
T(n) = 5*T(n-4) + 3*T(n-5) + 7c
and so on.
```

You see the coefficients are Fibonacci numbers themselves!

Call `F(n)` the `nth` Fibonacci number.  `F(n) = (phi^n + psi^n)/sqrt(5)` where `phi = (1+sqrt(5))/2` and `psi = -1/phi`, then we have:

```
T(n) = F(n)*2c + F(n-1)*c + (F(n+1)-1)*c
```

Here is some quick code to demonstrate:

```py
def fib_gen(n):
    """generates fib numbers to avoid rounding errors"""
    fibs=[1,1]
    for i in xrange(n-2):
        fibs.append(fibs[i]+fibs[i+1])
    return fibs

F = fib_gen(50) #just an example.
c=1

def T(n):
    """the recursive definiton"""
    if n == 1:
        return c
    if n == 2:
        return 2*c
    return T(n-1) + T(n-2) + c

def our_T(n): 
    n=n-2 #just because your intials were T(1) and T(2), sorry this is ugly!
    """our found relation"""
    return F[n]*2*c + F[n-1]*c + (F[n+1]-1)*c
```

and

```
>>> T(24)
121392
>>> our_T(24)
121392
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this general approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244323/analyzing-an-algorithm-with-recurrence-tn-tn-1-tn-2-tn-3/17249445#17249445).Please ask if you have more questions.

Comment: @Aravind..The link you provided was of great help!

Answer (score 4):

Is "worse than exponential" accurate enough for your purposes? The special case C=0 defines  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number, which you can see from the article is exponential. Assuming C is positive, your series will be growing faster than this. In fact, your series will lie between the Fibonacci series and a variant of the Fibonacci series in which the golden ratio is replaced by something very slightly larger.

Answer (score 3):

This type of recurrences are called: [non-homogeneous recurrence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_non-homogeneous_recurrence_relations) and you have to solve in the beginning homogeneous recurrence (the one without a constant at the end). If you are interested, read the math behind it.

I will show you an easy way. Just type your equation in [wolfram-alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29%20%3D%20T%28n-1%29%20%2B%20T%28n-2%29%20%2B%20C) and you will get:

[image]

So the complexity grows in the same way as either Lucas or Fibonacci number (the bigger of them).

But both of them have the same growth rate:

[image]
[image]

and therefore your growth rate is an exponential of the golden ratio: `O(phi^n)`