# How to solve this recurrence relation: T(n) = T(n-1) * T(n-2)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence

Consider this recurrence relation:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) * T(n-2)    n>2
T(1) = 1, T(2) = 2
```

How i can solve it? And finally: `T(n) = O(?)`

I think we should take log of both sides or something like.
But i have no idea to continue.

Comment: You can work your way by observing that the recurrence is transformed by taking logarithms to t(n) = t(n-1) + t(n-2), where t(n) = log T(n)...

Answer (score 1):

You start by taking the logarithm of both parts to get:

`log(T(n)) = log(T(n-1)) + log(T(n-2))`

Now you substitute it with `log(T(n))` to `K(n)` so you have to solve the problem [K(n) = K(n-1) + K(n-2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34310703/1090562). Doing similar thing you will get the solution

K(n) = c1 * F(n) + c2 * L(n), where F(n) is a [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) and L(n) is a [Lucas number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number) and c1, c2 are just some constants. So now to get your answer you just have to revert the logarithm.

So your solution is `e^(c1 * F(n) + c2 * L(n))`. Following my previous explanation the complexity of this is `O(e^(phi^n))`