# Solve recurrence: T(n) = T(n − 1) + T(n − 2) + 3

Tags: math, time-complexity, recurrence, master-theorem

T(1) = T(2) = 1, and for n > 2, T(n) = T(n − 1) + T(n − 2) + 3.

What Ive done so far:

```
T(n-1) = T(n-2) + T(n-3) + 3 + 3
T(n-2) = T(n-3) + T(n-4) + 3 + 3 + 3
T(n) = T(n-2) + 2T(n-3) + T(n-4) + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3
T(n) = T(1) + 2T(2) + T(n-4) + 3(n + 2)
```

Im not sure if this is right, and if it is, how do I get rid of T(n-4).

Comment: What exactly is your question? You want to calculate `T(n)` for `n>0`?

Comment: Get the function by solving the recurrence.

Comment: The recurrence implies `(T(n) + 3) = (T(n-1) + 3) + (T(n-2) + 3)`. Now if you define `F(n) = T(n) + 3` for all `n`, you get `F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)` for all `n > 2`. Does this remind you of anything?

Comment: Yeah, the fibonacci sequence. But how do you solve it?

Comment: @hhhh-adsa uh... see my answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complexity of the recursion: T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714365/complexity-of-the-recursion-tn-tn-1-tn-2-c)

Answer (score 3):

These types of recurrences are tricky, and the repeated expansion method will unfortunately get you nowhere. Observing the recursion tree will only give you an upper bound, which is often not tight.

Two methods I can suggest:

---

### 1. Substitution + Standard Theorem

Make the following variable substitution:

[image]

This is in the correct form for the [Akra-Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method), with parameters:

[image]

---

### 2. Fibonacci formula

The Fibonacci series has an explicit formula which can be derived by guessing a solution of the form `Fn = a^n`. Using this as an analogy, substitute a similar expression for `T(n)`:

[image]

Equating the constant and exponential terms:

[image]

Take the positive root because the negative root has absolute value less than 1, and will therefore decay to zero with increasing `n`:

[image]

Which is consistent with **(1)**.